# What is the Connection of the Heavenly Realms to Christ Jesus?

Tags: ephesians

Eph 2:6 BSB. And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus,

We are seated with him, in the Heavenlies.
This means Jesus is seated in the Heavenlies.

In Christ Jesus,
Christ is seated in Christ Jesus?
We and Christ are seated in the Heavenlies in Christ Jesus?

What is Paul trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question properly you are confused by the verbiage in the verse:

> Eph 2:6 BSB. And God raised us up **with Christ** and seated us **with Him** in the heavenly realms **in Christ Jesus,**

Based on this and many other translations, a literal interpretation could indicate that somehow Christ is raised up and seated in Christ. I never recognized how awkward this verse may appear, to some careful readers, until you pointed it out.
I think a more literal translation might actually make it more clear what Paul is actually saying.

Here's how an interlinear renders the text on biblehub.com:

[image: Interlinear from biblehub.com]
**Youngs literal translation translates it like this:**

> 6 and He raised us up together and seated us together in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus,
> -Ephesians 2:6

Notice how you no longer have the awkard "with Christ" & "with Him" language. In fact it doesn't say that all, but simply that *"He* [God] *raised us* [saints] *up together* [as saints] *and seated us* [saints] *together* [as saints] *in the heavenly realm in Christ.*
Taken more literally there is no way to misread the verse as somehow saying that Christ is raised up and seated in Christ.

The way that I understand this verse, is that all believers in Christ are together raised and seated in the heavenly places along with Christ via covenantal identity with Christ our Lord. Because he, our covenental head, has conqured and is seated in the heavenly places with God, it is the same as if we, by being subordinated under him in covenantal identity, have all also conqured and are raised up and seated in the heavenly places with God along with Christ and so are given favor by God in the inheritance because of Christ, our covenantal head, who is at God's right hand. And when he arrives again, so will arrive, with Jesus, the fullness of our covenental blessings which are made known to us through the covenantal promises.

Comment: Very Fine Answer. You seem to understand the verbage issue with the text. Is young Literal version a more closer redition of the greek text than other translations ?

Comment: You seem also to be of the opinion that the together will mean
Together - All saints. Not, Together- The saints and Jesus

Comment: @FaithMendel, Thank you.

Comment: @FaithMendel **Is young Literal version a more closer redition of the greek text than other translations?** Yes. It is more literal than the NIV and ESV for example, though it is itself not perfect. My view is that all translations are wrong, but some are useful. The Young's Literal Translation is very often quite useful.

Comment: @FaithMendel, **You seem also to be of the opinion that the together will mean Together - All saints. Not, Together- The saints and Jesus** Yes. I believe the passage relates believers to Jesus Christ and not the believers and Jesus to Jesus - which caused the awkwardness you pointed out.  Nothing in the verse forces us to embrace that akwardness.

Answer (score 2):

Paul opened his epistle with Ephesians 1:

> 1 Paul, an apostle of Christ Jesus by the will of God,
>
> To the saints in Ephesus, the faithful **in Christ Jesus**:
>
> 2 Grace and peace to you from God our Father and the Lord Jesus Christ.
>
> 3 Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us **in Christ** with every spiritual blessing **in the heavenly realms**. 4For He chose us **in Him** before the foundation of the world to be holy and blameless **in His presence**. In love 5 He predestined us for adoption as His sons through Jesus Christ, according to the good pleasure of His will, 6to the praise of His glorious grace, which He has freely given us **in the Beloved One**.
>
> 7 **In Him** we have redemption through His blood,

In the first 7 verses, Paul mentioned the concept of in-Christ 6 times! and connected this to the heavenly realms. This was the idea of being in union with Christ spiritually.
This theme continues to the rest of this epistle,
Eph 2:

> 6 And God raised us up with Christ and seated us **with Him** in the heavenly realms **in Christ** Jesus,

What is this "with Him" and "in Christ" at the same time?

Paul spoke of a spiritual reality. While we are alive on earth, we are dead in sin. But Christ died on our behalf and raised us up spiritually. Now we are alive spiritually in
Christ.

Where is Christ now?

Mark 16:

> 19
> After the Lord Jesus had spoken to them, He was taken up into heaven and **sat** down at the right hand of God.

Paul affirmed that Christ is seated in the heavenly realms. Because of our spiritual onion in Christ, we are also seated with Him in the heavenly realms spiritually.
This is a spiritual reality. We only need to believe as Paul did and wrote about it in his letter.

What is the Connection of the Heavenly Realms to Christ Jesus?

It is a spiritual connection, a spiritual reality.

Comment: So God Raised Christ to sit in the Heavenlies in Christ?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus...

Comment: That is very different from "God Raised Christ to sit in the Heavenlies in Christ".

Answer (score 0):

This is best explained by the consistent idea surrounding divine adoption and it logical extension that Jesus is both our brother and representative:

> Heb 2:11-13 - For both the One who sanctifies and those who are
> sanctified are of the same family. So Jesus is not ashamed to call
> them **brothers**. He says:
>
> “I will proclaim Your name to My brothers; I will sing Your praises
> **in the assembly**.”
>
> And again: “I will put My trust in Him.” And once again: “Here am I,
> and the children God has given Me.”

- Matt 12:48 - But Jesus replied, “Who is My mother, and who are My brothers?” Pointing to His disciples, He said, “Here are My mother and My brothers.
- Rom 8:29 - For those God foreknew, He also predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son, so that He would be the firstborn among many brothers.

Thus, Jesus is both our "brother" and our representative in "the assembly".  There could be no better person to represent us as our "advocate" (1 Tim 2:5) as Jesus claimed to be the only one who came from heaven and returned to heaven:

- John 1:18 - No one has ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is Himself God and is at the Father’s side, has made Him known.
- John 3:13 - No one has ascended into heaven except the One who descended from heaven—the Son of Man.
- John 3:31 - The One [= Jesus] who comes from above is above all. The one who is from the earth belongs to the earth and speaks as one from the earth. The One who comes from heaven is above all.
- John 6:38 - For I have come down from heaven, not to do My own will, but to do the will of Him who sent Me.
- John 8:38 - I speak of what I have seen in the presence of the Father
- John 13:1, 3 - It was now just before the Passover Feast, and Jesus knew that His hour had come to leave this world and return to the Father. Having loved His own who were in the world, He loved them to the very end. ... Jesus knew that the Father had delivered all things into His hands, and that He had come from God and was returning to God.
- John 16:27, 28 - for the Father himself loves you, because you have loved me and have believed that I came from God.  I came from the Father and have come into the world, and now I am leaving the world and going to the Father.”

Thus, when Jesus was seated on the heavenly throne after His resurrection, He became our representative (Heb 2:11, 12) or advocate/mediator (1 Tim 2:5).  Thus we may say:

- Eph 2:6 - And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus

Earlier in the previous chapter, Paul makes this comment:

- Eph 1:3 - Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly realms.
- Eph 1:22, 23 - And God put everything under His feet and made Him head over everything for the church, which is His body, the fullness of Him who fills all in all.

[Note, even today, people say they have a "seat in parliament/congress" despite never having visited the governing capital.  This is on the basis of their elected representative in the legal governing body.]

Answer (score 0):

The word “*together*” was used three times in Ephesians 2:5-6. It is describing a believers union with Christ in being “*quickened*” (Ephesians 2:5), “*raised*” (this verse), and seated “*in heavenly places*” (this verse). None of these things are possible on our own. It is only through union with Christ that any of this is attainable. A believers victory in the Christian life is dependent on dependency on Christ and not on themselves.

“*Made us sit*” (this verse), “*raised*” (Ephesians 1:20 and this verse), and “*quickened*” (Ephesians 2:1 and 5) are all in the **aorist** tense. This indicates something that God has already accomplished in Christ, not something that is off in the future.

To be raised up together with Christ and made to sit together “*in heavenly places*” indicates not only *location* but also a *position* of authority. It’s because of a believers position of being raised up with Christ that all things, including the demonic realm, are put under ‘our’ feet (Ephesians 1:22-23).

Believers can exercise this authority in this present evil age through preaching the Gospel, (Acts 4:30, Luke 5:24, and Mark 16:20). Since believers are resurrected with Jesus and seated with Him in heavenly places, what is true of Him is also true of them - in their born-again spirits.

Answer (score 0):

> And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus Eph 2:6 BSB.

The OP writes;
"We are seated with him, in the Heavenlies This means Jesus is sited in the Heavenlies'"

"In Christ Jesus, Christ is seated in Christ Jesus? We and Christ is seated in the Heavenlies in Christ Jesus?"

What is Paul trying to say?

> God exalted him to His right hand as Prince and Saviour, Acts 5:31

> Exalted, then, to the right hand of God, he has received from the Father the promised holy spirit  Acts 2:33

> He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation. Col 1:15

And the firstborn from the dead v18

> This hope we have as an anchor of the soul, a hope both sure and reliable and one which enters within the veil, 20 where Jesus has entered **as a forerunner for us**, having become a high priest forever Heb 6:19

The whole narrative of what Jesus accomplished is as the first human to go all the way. From mortality to immortality, from physical life to spirit life. Rom 6:9, 1Pet 3:18. He is the second and last Adam because the first one failed at the first test.

Believers in Christ, who God has called and enabled belief and faith are given salvation in Christ - as he lives, we too will live - even if we die. Or course, Paul is speaking of eternal life that we will have, just as Jesus was given at his resurrection. We too are figuratively seated with and in Christ at God's side. We cannot sit there on our own - but only in Jesus' righteousness.

When God said he was making man in His image - that was only going to be possible in Christ - he alone is in the true image of God.

> For those God foreknew he also predestined to be conformed to the image of his son, that he might be the firstborn among many brothers and sisters. Rom 8:29

So we are seated next to God **with** Christ, because we are his brothers and sisters

> To God’s holy people in Colossae, the faithful brothers and sisters in Christ: Grace and peace to you from God our Father. Col 1:2

And we are seated **in** Christ because we have our validity **in** Christ only

Answer (score 0):

**What is the Connection of the Heavenly Realms to Christ Jesus?**

> Eph 2:6 BSB. And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him
> in the heavenly realms in [ union]Christ Jesus,

[ the word "union" entered in verse by me]

And God raised us up: Who ?

Just because Adam sinned and died God did not open the way to heaven for all Christians. This is not supported by the scriptures, Jesus said the meek will inherit the earth. [Mt 5:5 KJV]. And Psalm 37:10-11 says:

Psalm 37:10-11 KJV

> 10 For yet a little while, and the wicked shall not be: yea, thou shalt
> diligently consider his place, and it shall not be.  11 But the meek
> shall inherit the earth; and shall delight themselves in the abundance
> of peace

What does God say about the earth? That he did not created theearth  for nothing, but he formed it to be inhabited.

Isaiah 45:18 ASV

> 18 For thus saith Jehovah that created the heavens, the God that
> formed the earth and made it, that established it and created it not
> [a]a waste, that formed it to be inhabited: I am Jehovah; and there is
> none else.

**Then who is going up to be seated with Jesus?**

God foresaw the existence of a class, or group,[Rev. 14:1-5] from among mankind that would be called to reign with Christ, as well as the requirements they would have to meet​—and this without designating ahead of time the specific individuals who would be chosen, for that would be contrary to his love and justice.Rom.8:29-30

Romans 8:29-30 NASB

> 29 For those whom He foreknew, He also predestined to become conformed
> to the image of His Son, so that He would be the firstborn among many
> brothers and sisters; 30 and these whom He predestined, He also
> called; and these whom He called, He also justified; and these whom He
> justified, He also glorified.

To the congregation of Smyrna,Jesus said:  Rev. 2:10.

> Prove yourself faithful even to death, and I will give you the crown
> of life.

Revelation 2:10 NASB

10 Do not fear what you are about to suffer. Behold, the devil is about to throw some of you into prison, so that you will be tested, and you will have tribulation for ten days. [a]Be faithful until death, and I will give you the crown of life.

**We are sitted with him, in the Heavenlies This means Jesus is sited in the Heavenlies**

As a perfect man in David’s royal line, he “offered one sacrifice for sins perpetually and sat down at the right hand of God [in 33 C.E.], from then on awaiting until his enemies should be placed as a stool for his feet.”​ HEB 10:11-13

Hebrews 10:12-13 NASB

> 12 But He, having offered one sacrifice for [a]sins for all time, sat
> down at the right hand of God, 13 waiting from that time onward until
> His enemies are made a footstool for His feet.

Here in Ephesians 1:11-14 Paul says that  God predestined a group of individuals [But not the individuals in the group] ahead of time that a limited number of humans would make up a secondary part of the seed of God’s woman and share with Christ in dispensing the benefits of the ransom. [Romans 8:28-30]

Ephesians 1:11-14 NASB

> 11 In Him we also have obtained an inheritance, having been
> predestined according to the purpose of Him who works all things in
> accordance with the plan of His will, 12 to the end that [b]we who
> were the first to hope in the [c]Christ would be to the praise of His
> glory. 13 In [d]Him, [e]you also, after listening to the message of
> truth, the gospel of your salvation—having also [f]believed, you were
> sealed in [g]Him with the Holy Spirit of the promise, 14 who is a
> first installment of our inheritance, in regard to the redemption of
> God’s own possession, to the praise of His glory.

In the heavenly realms In union with Christ: Here Paul speaks of the Saints /Holy people [Rom. 1:7 KJV/NRIV  Chosen race /1 Peter 2:9]as having already received “every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places,” though they were still on earth. The context shows that God “assigned [them] as heirs” with his Son in the heavenly inheritance and gave them a token of that inheritance. (Eph 1:11, 13, 14)